# How to apply HttpAuthenticationMechanism for only a certain url path?

Tags: java

I'm implementing role-based authorization in my application following the structure of the java ee 8 jwt security sample: https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee8-samples/tree/master/security/jwt.

1. I have a back-end application with session-based security and JSF. Authentication and Authorization is managed by a WebFilter:

   ```
   @WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/faces/*")
   public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {
   }
   ```
2. I have a REST api with JWT token-based security where I want to implement HttpAuthenticationMechanism for managing authentication and authorization.

I want these two different security mechanisms to live next to each other for personal interest and to prove that I can implement both ways. However, the HttpAuthenticationMechanism gets called everytime, also when browsing my JSF application. This leads to triggering of both mechanisms that are conflicting.

Is it possible to apply the HttpAuthenticationMechanism to only a certain url path? Like the urlPattern that's used in WebFilter? If so, how does one?

I want to use the HttpAuthenticationMechanism only to be triggered in my rest application:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    public RestApplication() {
    }
}
```

Comment: There may be a cleaner way, but you could implement your own HttpAuthenticationMechanism and have it delegate to whichever standard implementation you want to use.  You could then have your wrapper check the incoming URL, and trivially return whatever makes senses (success?) for URLs destined for the other mechanism, so that the other mechanism will kick in and do the real authentication.

Comment: @Steve that's indeed something I could do. I'm already implementing the interface by making a JWTAuthenticationMechanism, but that feels like a dirty way to solve this problem :). It is the last option for sure if there isn't a cleaner way for sure. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I had the same question and I ended up with [something like this](https://github.com/nuzayats/ee8security/blob/bcc64c3158ec4d0d22065f154b267688194e695b/src/main/java/ee8security/JwtHttpAuthenticationMechanism.java#L35-L38) . I'm looking for a better approach too

Comment: @Kohei Nozaki, thanks for sharing your solution. It's really useful for me as a temporary solution. I think, however, that there should be some functionality embedded in the API that only applies it to a certain part of the application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method "isProtected" in HttpMessageContext which will set to true/false depending on the security-constraints in web.xml

```
public AuthenticationStatus validateRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, HttpMessageContext httpMessageContext) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (!httpMessageContext.isProtected()) {
        return httpMessageContext.doNothing();
    }
    ...
```

So the first thing to do is check isProtected and only continue if the resource is supposed to be protected.

Now you can use security-constraint in web.xml as usual:

```
...
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted</web-resource-name>
        <description>Declarative security tests</description>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>somegroup</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description>no description</description>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <description>Somegroup</description>
    <role-name>somegroup</role-name>
</security-role>
...
```

Now authentication will only be done for URLs below the /protected/* pattern, anything else will be available unprotected

Wondering why this is not addressed in most of the tutorials/examples out there...

Credits goes to this link which seems to be the only one describing this (althoug there is a a missing "NOT" in the Listing No 16)
https://www.informatik-aktuell.de/entwicklung/programmiersprachen/authentication-mit-java-ee-8.html